# tesseract was crashing in Linux web app service when I use multiprocessing for extracting images into text. but same code working fine windows

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, python-multiprocessing, tesseract

```
        #for windows
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
        def ocr_single_image(image):
           img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
           config = r'--oem 3 --psm 3'
           text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=config, lang='eng')
           # logging.info(f"text -->{text}")
           return text


        pdf_name = "test.pdf"
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
          container = 'pdfs', blob = pdf_name)
        streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()
        content = streamdownloader.readall()
        #for windows
        images = convert_from_bytes(content,poppler_path='C:/Program Files/poppler/Library/bin') 
        # for Linux
        # images = convert_from_bytes(content)   
         
        # using multiprocessing
        num_pages = len(images)
        num_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
        logger.info(f"num cpu for use --> {num_cpu}")
        pool = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool(processes = num_cpu)
        page_chunks = [list(range(i, min(i + num_cpu, num_pages))) for i in range(0, num_pages, num_cpu)]
      
        results = []

        for chunk in page_chunks:
            chunk_results = pool.map(ocr_single_image, [images[i] for i in chunk])
            results.extend('\n'.join(chunk_results))

        # Close the pool of processes
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        
        texts =[]
        for i,txt in enumerate(results):
            texts.append(txt)
        
        texts = '\n'.join(texts)
        print(texts)
        # using multiprocessing

        # With out multiprocessing below code working fine in windows and Linux server(App service).
        #texts =[] 
        #for image in images:
        #     texts.append(ocr_single_image(image))
        #texts = '\n'.join(texts)
        #print(texts)
        #With out multiprocessing below code working fine in windows and Linux server(App service).
```

With out multiprocessing, it's working local (windows) and linux web app service using docker working fine

```
texts =[] 
for image in images:
    texts.append(ocr_single_image(image))
texts = '\n'.join(texts)
print(texts)
```

then changes the code to below, then it's working in local (windows). using linux web app service with docker, not extracting it's crashing and sometime takeing more then 5000 sec

```
# using multiprocessing
        num_pages = len(images)
        num_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
        logger.info(f"num cpu for use --> {num_cpu}")
        pool = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool(processes = num_cpu)
        page_chunks = [list(range(i, min(i + num_cpu, num_pages))) for i in range(0, num_pages, num_cpu)]
      
        results = []

        for chunk in page_chunks:
            chunk_results = pool.map(ocr_single_image, [images[i] for i in chunk])
            results.extend('\n'.join(chunk_results))

        # Close the pool of processes
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        
        texts =[]
        for i,txt in enumerate(results):
            texts.append(txt)
        
        texts = '\n'.join(texts)
        print(texts)
        # using multiprocessing
```

please help me on crashing linux (web app service with docker while using multiprocessing)